# How to treat such questions?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

Today I encountered an answer in "Late Answers" queue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29071888/4169008. It contains an answer (at least a sort of), but in the same time it looks like a question. I think, to choose "No action needed" is correct here, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an answer. The other answer doesn't work (and they don't know why), so they've provided an alternative solution instead. Even if it did contain a question, you shouldn't delete the post if it contained an answer. It would be a different story if the post simply consisted of "the other answer doesn't work" without an alternative solution.